# How to save two canvas(outer and inner) as png using fabric js in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, canvas, fabricjs

[image]

while i save canvas it only saves outer canvas and ignores inner canvas

```
 //html

<button type="button" (click)="save()">save</button>
<div class="outercanvas">
      <canvas id="outercanvas"  width="500" height="500"></canvas>  
</div>
<div class="outerCanvas">
    <canvas id="outerCanvas" width="140" height="170" ></canvas>  
</div>

//ts code

canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('outercanvas');
canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas("innerCanvas");
save(){
 window.open(this.canvas.toDataURL('png'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofc because you never asked it to save the innercanvas just like you did for outercanvas.

```
save(){
 window.open(this.canvas.toDataURL('png'));
}
```

To save inner canvas as separately you can call same for inner canvas.

```
save(){
 window.open(this.canvas.toDataURL('png')); //outercanvas
 window.open(this.canvas1.toDataURL('png')); //innercanas
}
```

If you **want to save both canvases in one image** then follow below steps

1. Take output of inner canvas
2. Place that image over outercanvas using `fabric.Image.fromURL()`
3. Save the output of outer canvas
4. Remove the image from outercanvas, so it will be like, image never exist

Note: In 2nd step you have to position the image, use left and top property for or that, if you want to place it in center using `canvas.centerObject(img);`