# Apply frame image on top of Fabric JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabric JS to allow the user to have an interactive experience on my React app. Is it possible to apply a frame around a Fabric JS that is taken from an image? For instance, if the canvas is 400x400 px I can resize an image of a frame that is transparent in the middle to 410x410px and apply it on top of the canvas for the user to see? I have attached two images for reference.

[image]
[image]

## Edit: This is the code I am using for zooming in

```
 const zoomIn = useCallback(() => {
    // Get original height of canvas
    const canvasDimensions = getInitialCanvasSize()

    let zoom = HTML5Canvas.getZoom()
    zoom += 0.2
    if (zoom >= 2) zoom = 2
    HTML5Canvas.setZoom(zoom)

    HTML5Canvas.setWidth(canvasDimensions.width * HTML5Canvas.getZoom());
    HTML5Canvas.setHeight(canvasDimensions.height * HTML5Canvas.getZoom());

  }, [HTML5Canvas])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for canvas's border in fabricjs [canvas docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html)

But you can still achieve this easily using following steps.

### PART 1: Creating the Illusion of border

#### CSS Method

1. First one can easily create CSS border around the canvas.
   Best way to do this is to create div around canvas, as fabricjs split canvas in 2 while running.
2. You can create slider to control width and color/image for div's border.
   This will looks like exactly your second image with customization.

OR

#### Another Canvas Method

Behind current canvas put this second canvas and control its width and image.
`I don't recommend this one, as this will make it more complex to implement.`

### PART 2: Making Illusion real

#### If you used CSS METHOD

Now you get what your canvas looks like. You have `width` of border, `image/color` of border.

**Steps**:

1. Create new canvas (lets' call it **2nd Canvas**) of `410px` if canvas's width `400px` with border of `5px`.
2. Export main canvas as image and put it over **2nd Canvas**. And now you can export this as final image.
   For 2nd step check my answer on this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66801489/how-to-save-two-canvasouter-and-inner-as-png-using-fabric-js-in-angular/66812754#66812754)

#### If you used Another Canvas Method

Directly follow above 2nd step

> Export main canvas as image and put it over **2nd Canvas**. And now you can export this as final image.
> For 2nd step check my answer on this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66801489/how-to-save-two-canvasouter-and-inner-as-png-using-fabric-js-in-angular/66812754#66812754)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this answer worked, at first I preferred the first answer but I realised that since I set the width of the fake frame to a fixed width, the frame became unproportionally thick when I "zoomed out" / made the canvas smaller. But I think perhaps this can be solved by the second approach.

Comment: Great! I have a small question Are both canvases changes zoom level simultaneously?

Comment: In my case there is only 1 canvas, not sure if this answers the question but this is the code I use to zoom in. I added it as an edit on the bottom of the original question.